# TypeError in graphics.py

Tags: python, mouseevent, zelle-graphics

I'm trying to make a rudimentary cookie clicker: every time you click the cookie, a counter on the bottom of it goes up by one. whenever I click the cookie, I get this wonderful error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

I've figured out that something in my code is probably giving a return value of `None' for my program to spit out this error but I can't seem to figure out what.

```
# imports and variables

win = GraphWin('Cookie Clik', 500, 600)

# the cookie itself (center at 250, 250) and displaying the counter

if math.sqrt((win.mouseX - 250)^2 + (win.mouseY - 250)^2) < 200: # <- here's where I get an error
    # add one to the counter
```

I'm basically using pythag to determine how far away the mouse is from a point (the center of the circle) and if it's less than the radius, add one to the counter

Comment: what library is `GraphWin` from? Most likely,`win.mouseX` and/or `win.mouseY` don't exist

Comment: "but I can't seem to figure out what." Well, you know which line the error occurs on, and you know that the error results from trying to subtract with `NoneType` and `int`. You should be able to narrow down which value is unexpectedly `None`; i.e. one of the ones you're trying to subtract from :)

Comment: @SuperStormer it's from graphics.py

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yeah, I know the MouseX/Y is probably the root of the problem but i have no idea how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

First, in this expression:

```
sqrt((win.mouseX - 250)^2 + (win.mouseY - 250)^2)
```

`^` isn't *exponentiation*, it's *xor*!  You want `**`.  Next, there is no:

```
win.mouseX
```

instead you call `win.getMouse()` which returns a `Point` instance.  Here's a rough sketch of what you're trying to do:

```
from graphics import *
from math import sqrt

RADIUS = 20

win = GraphWin('Cookie Clik', 500, 600)

location = Point(250, 300)

cookie = Circle(location, RADIUS)
cookie.draw(win)

counter = 0

text = Text(Point(300, 250), counter)
text.draw(win)

while True:
    point = win.getMouse()

    if sqrt((point.getX() - location.getX()) ** 2 + (point.getY() - location.getY()) ** 2) < RADIUS:
        counter += 1

        text.setText(counter)
```

The next thing to add would be somewhere to click to get out of the program!